# Artemis cluster config vs. standalone broker config

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to set up a HA cluster of artemis brokers locally on my machine and want to demonstrate **load balancing** and **failover behavior** in a simple example. (before that I tried also a standalone broker).
For my cluster I am using udp broadcast and discovery. I set up two brokers for the beginning.

In all those examples for cluster, there was always that **auto-created list of acceptors** (artemis, stomp,...), where we could add wildcard expressions or prefixes.

Why we don't need them in a cluster anymore? And what does netty-acceptor exactly stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or you not you need a particular `acceptor` configured in your `broker.xml` is really up to your use-case. Many of the examples use the default `broker.xml` which has an `acceptor` configured for every protocol which the broker supports. However, some examples (e.g. many of the clustered ones) only have the exact acceptors which they need to demonstrate the example's functionality.

I searched through all the configuration files of all the examples and the text `netty-acceptor` is only ever used as the `name` for an `acceptor`. The `name` of an `acceptor` simply identifies it uniquely among all the acceptors which are configured.

To be clear, any broker, whether it is clustered or not, can accept connections from any supported protocol granted the proper `acceptor` is configured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, this is only acceptor name. I should have asked different. What I actually meant were the**protocols** and further options, which are specified in the default broker.xml and which are mostly missing in cluster examples. So can I specify them also in cluster configs ans use them exactly in the way as for a standalone broker?